# Ruby exercise regarding Hash

Tags: ruby

I was working on this Ruby exercise:

> Write a function, `letter_count(str)` that takes a string and
>   returns a hash mapping each letter to its frequency. Do not include
>   spaces.

This is a solution:

```
def letter_count(str)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  str.each_char do |char|
    counts[char] += 1 unless char == " "
  end
  counts
end
```

What does `counts[char] += 1` mean? What does `char == " "` mean?

Comment: [+=](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+plus+equals)

Comment: `counts` is a hash, so `counts[char]` is the value of the hash for the key equal to the value of the local variable `char`. For example, `count["a"]` is the value for the key `"a"`. `"a"` is a string (even though it consists of a single character). Ruby does not have character objects. Ruby expands `counts[char] += 1` to `counts[char] = counts[char] + 1` and then executes it. `counts[char] == " "` returns `true` if `char` is a string consisting of a single space character. `Hash.new(0)` is the crux of the problem. You need to understand that.

Comment: Very good explanation, I think I missed the important 0 in Hash.new(0), and thank you very much Cary

Answer (score 3):

> What in the world does counts[char] += 1 mean??

`+=` is shorthand for "increment by and assign", i.e. this could be written as:

```
count = counts[char] # retrieve the value at index "char"
count = count + 1    # add one
counts[char] = count # set the value at index "char" to the new value
```

> Also what does char == " " mean?

`==` is the equality operator. `a == b` returns `true` if `a` and `b` have the same value. So `char == " "` returns true if `char` is the space character. In this case the equality test is inverted by the trailing `unless`, so it ends up meaning "add 1 to the count for this character unless the character is a space".

Comment: Thank you, I missed the space in between quotes :D

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, `+=` desugars to an `=` and a `+`. So `counts[char] += 1` becomes `counts[char] = counts[char] + 1`. Now, normally, if a key does not exist in the hash, the hash access method `[]` would return nil, which is why we passed 0 into the constructor. Passing a value into the constructor makes that the 'default' return value if a key does not exist. So if `counts[char]` exists, it adds one to it, and if it doesn't, it initializes it to `0 + 1`, which is just 1.

As for the comparison at the end, `unless char == " "` is a suffix conditional, a Perlism that migrated over into Ruby. In Ruby, you can write conditions at the end of a line, so the following three are equivalent.

```
# One
if not foo
  bar
end
# Two
bar if not foo
# Three
bar unless foo
```

The problem description said to exclude spaces, so `unless char == " "` ensures that the increment operation in the hash will run unless the character is a space.

Comment: Anyone new to Ruby is not likely to understand what "desugars" means.

Comment: Thank you so much Silvio, this has cleared up a lot. I think I will understand better if I sleep on it.

Answer (score 1):

> What in the world does counts[char] += 1 mean??

`a += 1` and `a = a + 1` are equivalent. Besides, with `counts = Hash.new(0)`, `0` will be set to the value of a new key(if the key doesn't exit). So, if the `char` is new, `counts[char]` become `1` with `counts[char] += 1`. If it's the second time to see `char`, `counts[char]` become `2` with `counts[char] += 1` because `1` has been set to `counts[char]` already.

> Alsowhat does char == " " mean?

`char == " "` returns true if `char` is " "(space character).

Comment: Thank you Masashi, I think the 0 at the Hash.new(0) is what I left out and confused me.